# Wifi router near fusebox

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

Can I place a WiFi router near our fusebox?

My concern is whether the fusebox will disturb the WiFi.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely you will have no issues aside from the metal fuse box attenuating the wifi signal in one direction. Fuse boxes are typically on an outside wall, though, so this shouldn't cause a problem. No harm can come from trying it out.

Comment: Good answer. I'll add: Just be sure not to place the Wi-Fi router *inside* the metal fuse box. I actually had a friend call me once asking why he wasn't getting the range/coverage he expected from his new AP, and it turned out he had placed it *inside* the metal box housing his patch panel. D'oh!

Also don't place it on top of or touching the metal fuse box, as metal that close to an antenna can act as a passive element (basically becoming a part of the antenna system) and impair the antenna characteristics of your AP.